object has no attribute '__fields_set__'. Did you mean: '__fields__'?
I am using pydantic-settings==2.4.0
and  trying to configure my settings class with yaml file
My code:
import os
import yaml

from pydantic.v1 import AnyHttpUrl, BaseSettings, EmailStr, validator, BaseModel, Field
from typing import List, Optional, Union, Any
from pathlib import Path
...

class ServiceSettingsYaml(BaseSettings):
    backend_cors_origins: List[AnyHttpUrl] = []
    kafka_host: str = None
    kafka_port: str = None
    kafka_topics: str = None
    kafka_instance: str = None
    file_encoding: str = "utf-8"

    db_user: str = None
    db_password: str = None
    db_host: str = None
    db_port: str = None
    db_name: str = None
    sqlalchemy_database_url: str = None

    def __init__(self, config_file_path: str = "configs/dev-config.yaml"):
        config = load_yaml_config(config_file_path)

        print("AAA_ ", config.kafka_consumer) # prints {'host': 'kafka', 'port': 9092, 'kafka_topics': 'my_topic'}
        self.kafka_host: str = config.kafka_consumer["host"]

I have an error in the last code from my listing:
File "/usr/src/app/app/main.py", line 12, in <module>
51_fetcher_new-consumer-1   |     from app.core.config import settings
51_fetcher_new-consumer-1   |   File "/usr/src/app/app/core/config.py", line 144, in <module>
51_fetcher_new-consumer-1   |     settings = ServiceSettingsYaml()
51_fetcher_new-consumer-1   |   File "/usr/src/app/app/core/config.py", line 131, in __init__
51_fetcher_new-consumer-1   |     self.kafka_host: str = config.kafka_consumer["host"]
51_fetcher_new-consumer-1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/v1/main.py", line 405, in __setattr__
51_fetcher_new-consumer-1   |     self.__fields_set__.add(name)
51_fetcher_new-consumer-1   | AttributeError: 'ServiceSettingsYaml' object has no attribute '__fields_set__'. Did you mean: '__fields__'?

How to configure my class with help of yaml file properly?

import os
import yaml
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict
from pydantic import AnyHttpUrl, Field
from typing import List, Optional

def load_yaml_config(config_file_path: str):
    """Load configuration from a YAML file."""
    with open(config_file_path, 'r') as file:
        return yaml.safe_load(file)

class ServiceSettingsYaml(BaseSettings):
    # Define model configuration
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file_encoding='utf-8')

    # Existing fields with defaults
    backend_cors_origins: List[AnyHttpUrl] = []
    file_encoding: str = "utf-8"

    # Kafka settings
    kafka_host: Optional[str] = None
    kafka_port: Optional[str] = None
    kafka_topics: Optional[str] = None
    kafka_instance: Optional[str] = None

    # Database settings
    db_user: Optional[str] = None
    db_password: Optional[str] = None
    db_host: Optional[str] = None
    db_port: Optional[str] = None
    db_name: Optional[str] = None
    sqlalchemy_database_url: Optional[str] = None

    def __init__(self, config_file_path: str = "configs/dev-config.yaml", **data):
        config = load_yaml_config(config_file_path)
        
        merged_data = {}
        
        if 'kafka_consumer' in config:
            kafka_config = config['kafka_consumer']
            merged_data.update({
                'kafka_host': kafka_config.get('host'),
                'kafka_port': str(kafka_config.get('port')),
                'kafka_topics': kafka_config.get('kafka_topics')
            })
        
        if 'database' in config:
            db_config = config['database']
            merged_data.update({
                'db_host': db_config.get('host'),
                'db_user': db_config.get('user'),
                # Add other database-related fields
            })
        
        # Merge with any additional data passed to __init__
        merged_data.update(data)
        
        super().__init__(**merged_data)

settings = ServiceSettingsYaml()

The main issues with your previous code were related to the transition from Pydantic v1 to Pydantic v2:
Specifically, these lines were problematic:
def __init__(self, config_file_path: str = "configs/dev-config.yaml"):
    config = load_yaml_config(config_file_path)
    print("AAA_ ", config.kafka_consumer) # prints {'host': 'kafka', 'port': 9092, 'kafka_topics': 'my_topic'}
    self.kafka_host: str = config.kafka_consumer["host"]


The line self.kafka_host: str = config.kafka_consumer["host"] was causing an AttributeError because in Pydantic v2, the way of setting attributes has changed.

In Pydantic v1, BaseSettings had a different initialization mechanism compared to Pydantic v2. Your custom __init__ method was not properly integrating with the Pydantic settings loading process.

The previous approach of manually setting attributes after loading a YAML file is not the recommended way in Pydantic v2. The new version provides more robust methods for configuration management.


